# Undefined reference in a simple makefile test CPP

Tags: c++, makefile

I was trying to make a simple makefile to learn how to use headers and make in C++, however it doesn't seems to work, returning "undefined reference" at the end. What is going wrong here? I don't believe there are any mistakes in the .cpp or .hpp files, and I searched a bit about makefile to be sure that it should be working.

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "test.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    test::print();

    return 0;
}
```

For test.hpp and test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#pragma once

class test{

private:
   
public:
    static void print();
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "test.hpp"

using namespace std;

static void print(){
    cout << "aaaaaa\n";
}
```

Finally, the makefile:

```
all:
    rm *.o
    g++ -c -g *.cpp
    g++ *.o -o main.exe
    rm *.o
```

Comment: In `test.cpp`, the `static void print() {...` is not the same as `void test::print() {...`

Comment: @Eljay why? Are't static used for functions called without using instances?

Comment: I removed the static in the test.cpp and it worked, so it should be declared only in the .hpp?

Comment: Get a good C++ book. your code declared a static *class* member function called `print`, but implemented a global function (no class specifier) called `print`. They're not the same `print`. You never implemented the former, and the latter wasn't what `main` was calling.

Comment: The keyword `static` means different things in different contexts.  This code was using `static` in the "class function" sense, and in another place in the "internal linkage to the translation unit" sense.